# Has any NHL team ever won a game after being down 0-5?

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl

Has any NHL team ever won a game after being down 0-5? It would clearly be quite difficult and arguably miraculous.

Comment: Evidently, it is not arguable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has happened six times in NHL history so is not as uncommon as you suspect:

- [1982-04-10, Edmonton vs Los Angeles](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/198204100LAK.html) (playoffs)
- [1987-01-26, Calgary vs Toronto](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/198701260TOR.html)
- [1999-03-03, Colorado vs Florida](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/199903030FLA.html)
- [2000-11-29, St. Louis vs Toronto](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/200011290TOR.html)
- [2008-02-19, New York Rangers vs Montreal](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/200802190MTL.html)
- [2009-10-12, Calgary vs Chicago](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/200910120CHI.html)

Comment: Intriguing to me is that only the first two were in the "high scoring" era; the last four were in the more mundane modern era of actual defense, where 5 goals at all was fairly unusual.

Comment: @Joe There are [4 more instances between 1983 and 1989 where teams came back from a 5 goal deficit if not 5-0 to win](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comeback_(sports)#Regular_season_2). More modern overtime rules I suspect also play a part - e.g. the Canadiens win in 2008 was in a shootout which would have been a tie under old rules.

Comment: That's a good point - so would the playoff game in 1982 had it been in the regular season!  And then of course you have the Colorado game where they came back and won 7-5 in regulation, because the 1999 Avs were just that good...  that game also had the rare double hat trick (Bure and Forsberg).

Comment: For perspective, about 60k NHL games have been played to date, making about 0.01% of games a 0-5 comeback. Of course, the vast majority of games never get to 0-5, so the likelihood of coming back if that deficit is actually reached will be quite a bit higher than that. Agree we're likely out of "miracle" territory, which could be benchmarked with the 1000:1 odds (0.1% chance) of 1980's Miracle on Ice. It would be miraculous for a random game to result in a 0-5 comeback, but seeing a comeback in a 0-5 game might not be.

Comment: Maybe also show us how to find the answer?

Comment: @NikeDattani I would think you could ask a question about that (how to find answers like this more generally, at least) - it would be on topic here in my opinion, and also might be on topic on [opendata.se], but check there as I'm not sure exactly what they would consider on topic in this area.  Here only the sports-related side of things would be on topic, but I don't see why it wouldn't be.

Answer (score 4):

Wayne Gretzky probably doesn't want to remember this one, but the [Oilers lost to the Kings 6-5 in 1982](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/198204100LAK.html) in the playoffs (Game 3 of the Smythe division semi-finals that year) after leading 5-0 after 2 periods. Not only did the Kings come back from down 5-0, but they came back *entirely in the 3rd period and OT*, scoring their last 3 goals of regulation in less than six minutes, and the tying goal on the power play with only 5 seconds remaining in regulation.

Contributing to the demise were a *ton* of penalties in the second half of the third period - this was not super uncommon back then, but there was a ton of offsetting penalties leading to quite a long time of 4-on-4 play, which undoubtedly simplified things, plus the high-stick major by Gary Unger at exactly 15:00 that meant that the Kings were able to play two men up after pulling their goalie for the last three minutes.  That plus some shenanigans with goaltenders that gave the Kings a breather allowed them to finally score at nearly the last second.